# Eloquent multiple row relationship with Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent, eloquent-relationship

I can't rack my head how to create a relationship that involves having two records of the same model in another table. I am trying to keep record of company acquisitions (M&A) in a certain geography and in order to do that I have to keep record of the acquirer and the acquired both of which I may or may not have in our company table.

Here's a simple example:

ABC acquires XYZ

**Acquisition table**

```
acquirer | acquired | type          | acquirer_id | acquiree_id
ABC        XYZ        acquisition     34            58
```

**Company table**

```
id | name | slug 
34 | ABC  | abc
58 | XYZ  | xyz
```

I'm not entirely sure if this is a good approach but I would like to be able to display the acquisition on both profiles.

**E.g:** On ABC's profile, we show that ABC acquired XYZ and on XYZ's profile, we show that XYZ has been acquired by ABC. I'll need to get the company's slug (if company exists) so that I am able to link to it while showing the acquisition.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this answers your problem.
You can declare two relationship in your Acquisition Model.

```
public function acquirerCompany() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Company::class, 'acquirer_id');
}

public function acquireeCompany() {
    return $this->belongsTo(Company::class, 'acquiree_id');
}
```

Now if you want to get the company slug:

```php
// acquierer
$acquisition->acquirerCompany->slug;

// acquieree
$acquisition->acquireeCompany->slug;
```